# React: prevent function component from rerender when parents components className changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets say i have these two simple function components:

```
const Otto = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Otto gets rerendered!')
    })
    return <div></div>
}

const App = () => {
    const [toggle, set] = useState(true)
    return (
        <div
            onClick={() => set(!toggle)}
            className={`App ${toggle ? 'default' : 'dark'}`}
        >
            <Otto />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Now everytime the toggle `state` changes, the `<Otto />` gets rerendered. How can i prevent the childrens rerender and still toggle the className? I searched and tried everything, but sadly to no avail.